# MP4 video is played via CPanel, but not played via <video> tag

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, video, cpanel

There is a video file in my website. This video is not played via the Firefox browser in my website, This is the [Video Player](http://mheidari.me/test.html) url and it is the code

```
<video width="800" height="450" controls>
   <source src="162_6383266.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

, But when I click on it in the CPanel It is played. I mean this

[image]

and it is the result

[image]

Why the video is not played via that code, but it is played via the CPanel? I also seen some videos that are not playing in Chrome as well. But the above example is playing in Chrome

Comment: In the console log for Firefox I get `Specified "type" attribute of "video/mp4" is not supported. Load of media resource 162_6383266.mp4 failed.` and if I try to play that link - http://mheidari.me/162_6383266.mp4 - it downloads it (and plays in VLC) rather than plays inline. What output do you get from `canPlayType('video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"')` on that page?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal it says `probably`

Comment: @the8472 what do you mean?

Comment: works on current builds of Firefox - are you running latest version, and what OS?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal The firefox version is `47.0`. I tried on both localhost which is Windows7 and remote server which is CloudLinux. The same problem persists for some videos in Chrome :(